# Why would i learn erlang or haskell?

Tags: haskell, erlang

Why should I learn Haskell, Erlang or other concurrent languages if I am already an OCJP and can master C/C++?

People have a craze of learning Erlang, Haskell, Oz, Prolog. But is it really necessary? Does it have any scope in a programmers carreer?

Comment: If you think you have mastered C/C++, you should try to learn C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza I mean I am good at memory management and stuff...

Comment: Because you want to - or don't want to, but can rationalize it for other reasons. (But, more seriously, the reason to learn Erlang *and* Haskell *and* .. is that they are *very different* from C or C++. Go polygots!)

Comment: This is merely an opinion based question which isn't allow in SO. Probably you should look up on the pros/cons of each different languages. And what are the uses of different languages.

Comment: Thats it? No carreer scope?

Comment: That doesn't mean you are any good at C++.

Comment: From your question I can take that you are already an extremely good programmer. Then you should focus on applying your skills, instead of trying to achieve the impossible (becoming an even better programmer).

Comment: Based on opinions, not a real SO question

Comment: Have you read [Why Haskell Matters](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Why_Haskell_Matters)? Its a good summary.

Comment: The reason why I learned Haskell was because it seemed interesting, and since has become very influential in how I structure programs even in imperative OO languages.  Why not learn it for the sake of learning it, even if you don't use it professionally?  Who knows?  Maybe having it on your resume would spark the interest of a recruiter leading to an awesome job, even if that position doesn't use Haskell.  It's landed me a few interviews by just having it mentioned.

Comment: @bheklilr amazing. Thanks for the sweet reply.

Answer (score 13):

The main reason to learn new programming language is not in learning just another programming language but to learn new programming paradigms, techniques and tools. Once I learned Prolog I started to write very different C code. It happen again with Perl and again with Erlang. It change way how to you will see problems and how you decompose them into manageable chunks and also way how you will implement them in readability and maintainability sense. But don't forgot learn how to write Perlish, Haskellish and Erlangish and whatever way. If you will write C like code in all those languages it will be waste of time.

Comment: Thankyou sir. This was the kind of answer I was looking. Will learning haskell change my coding style?

Comment: @user3182942: Yes, definitely. But I think Haskell is too big leap from C/C++. It can work but it can hurt a lot at beginning. I would try Erlang or some Lisp/Scheme or OCaml first. The Haskell's laziness and monads can make bad impression for starters and you can overuse them. Especially immutability and lack of any loops in Erlang can change your way to think and prepare you to next step and I would recommend it first. But it's just mine opinion.

Comment: how would you repeat steps without loops?

Comment: With recursion ;-) for example if you would like make list of numbers from 1 to 10 you write in `Erlang one_to_ten() -> one_to_ten(1).`
`one_to_ten(10) -> [10]; one_to_ten(N) -> [N|one_to_ten(N+1)].` See [`lists:seq/2`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L236)

Comment: Amazing. But that would make my style an "avoid loops" style. Will that be good? Coz recursion is not efficient as it makes big memory heap.

Comment: If you use tail call recursion it is as efficient as loop. For example `one_to_n(N) when is_integer(N) -> one_to_n(N, []).`
`one_to_n(N, L) when N < 1 -> L; one_to_n(N, L) -> one_to_n(N-1, [N|L]).` is as efficient as loop. Compiler makes just jump. You can make same trick in C as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the enlightenment sir. 

Answer (score 3):

Haskell is a functional programming language. I had the chance to learn few things about Haskell last year and i can say it was something new.

I think you should dive into Haskell, you'll have to use only recursive functions as there is no loops. It helped me a lot to improve my programming methods.

Give it a try and if you don't like it, just try something else.